# How can I address the error of "flutter pub get"

Tags: android, flutter, dart

After typing
"flutter clean" ->  "flutter pub cache repair" ->  "flutter pub get"
android studio give me below message

[image]

I don't know how to resolve, please someone help me.

I reinstalled all the suite that flutter needs so many times, but it still did not work, I have already drained my brain.

my pubspec.yaml like this
[image]

Comment: Does it work for you in a plain terminal?

Comment: Nope, I have already tried many times, but , yeb, it did not work.

Comment: could you show your pubspec.yaml?

Comment: I upload it above！

Comment: try to run `flutter doctor`, it will show you if you have any issue with the flutter setup.

Comment: You most likely have some weird character in your pubspec file, try to remove it and re-create it. Can you post the content of your pubspec file instead of a screenshot?